# Select $7$ switches among $60$ of which one has failed

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a computer network with $60$ switching nodes. If one node has failed, in how many ways can seven nodes be selected without encountering the failed node?

I set this problem up as $\binom {59} 7$, but that comes out to over $341$ million, which definitely doesn't seem right to me. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you think that 341 million is not right?

Comment: It just seemed like an extremely high value for a network with only 60 nodes (looking at 59 of them). Is 341 million possible?

Comment: You just proved it is possible!

Comment: Remember that $\binom{n}k$ grows at the speed of $n^k$ (assuming $k\leq n-k$) so we are talking about soemthing on the magnitude of $59^7$, a very large number.

Comment: @smittywerbenjagermanjensen If the answer addresses your concerns you should consider accepting it. If it does not, you should ask a clarifying question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct. The formula you used is exactly the right one to use. The reason this is bothering you is that you're forgetting that, when $b$ is small, the function $f(x)={x\choose b}$ acts like a polynomial. Try writing out the definition in terms of factorials and maybe then this rate of growth will make sense. The answer, for small $b$, is approximately $\frac{x^b}{b!}$, and $59^7/7!$ is a large number.

Comment: It is fair for small $b$ to ignore the decrease in numerator factors from $59$, but you should not ignore the $b!$ in the denominator.  Here it is $5040$

Comment: Good point. Added.